# Protractor-perf test script shows error at 'require('..') line

Tags: protractor

I'm new to **protractor-perf**. I have installed it and tried to execute a simple script that I had executed using protractor earlier. The following are the errors I'm facing:

1. If I use the line **var PerfRunner = require('..');** and initialize it as 
   **var perfRunner = new PerfRunner(protractor,browser);**- I'm getting the error **"Cannot find module '..' "**
2. If I use **var PerfRunner = require('protractor-perf');** and initialize it as **var perfRunner = new PerfRunner(protractor);** as per this link http://blog.nparashuram.com/2014/11/protractor-perf-performance-regression.html - I'm getting the error **"Cannot read property 'params' of undefined"**
3. If I use **var PerfRunner = require('protractor-perf');** and initialize it as **var perfRunner = new PerfRunner(protractor, browser);** - the test starts executing but the browser just hangs. There is no progress and it doesn't halt as well.

I'm using Chrome version 44.0, protractor-perf version 0.1.11 and protractor version 1.4.0

I do not know if I've made some mistake during installation or I'm making one in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor-perf works fine with chrome as well.
This issue is might be because of incorrect location of protractor-perf folder.

try giving absolute path

```
var PerfRunner = require('C:/Users/shrutid/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor-perf');
var perfRunner = new PerfRunner(protractor, browser);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that chromedriver does not work properly with new versions of Chrome (I don't know why). You can use firefox instead of Chrome to launch your tests. It's works for me.

Comment: In order to use chrome Browser you need to have compatible versions of Following software. : Chrome Browsers, Chrome Driver, Protractor.js Version.